# Run JS function in WebDriver/TestNG with Javascript Executor to check A/B test classified

Tags: javascript, selenium, automation, webdriver, testng

I'm doing an automated test with TestNG/WebDriver that check if my link has classified for my live A/B test..but it keeps getting an error. New to automation, so can't see what's going on here..

The code should: check if the variable Tnt exists on the page, if it does, the test is classified, if it doesn't, make a request to the tool to change the page split, then refresh the page without cache, and so the test will run again, until `testClassified = true`

Edited(trying to solve) (**on bold**)
my test function (that is on the page object):

```
public void checkTestWasClassifiedLive(String testId, String testSplit) {
        **Boolean testClassified;**

        do {
            testClassified = (**Boolean**) this.js.executeScript(
                                            "checkClassified = function() {  "
                                            + "     var testClassified = false;"
                                            +       "if (window.Tnt !== undefined) { "
                                            +       "       if(window.Tnt.tests[arguments[0]].length > 0) {"
                                            +       "           testClassified = true;"
                                            +       "       }"
                                            +       "} "
                                            +       "else {"
                                            +   "       if(window.tool !== undefined) {"
                                            +   "           window.tool.getOffer({"
                                            +   "               'mbox'    : '...',"
                                            +   "               'params'  : {'splitOverride' : parseInt(arguments[1])},"
                                            +   "               'success' : function(offers) {"
                                            +   "                               window.location.reload(true);"
                                            +   "                           },"
                                            +   "               'error'   : function(status, error) {},"
                                            +   "               'timeout' : 5000"
                                            +   "           });" 
                                            +   "       }"
                                            +       "}"
                                            +       "return testClassified;"
                                            + "}"
                                            + "checkClassified();", testId, testSplit);
            System.out.println("isTestClassified: ");
            System.out.println(testClassified);
        } while(testClassified == false);
        System.out.println("done");
    }
```

the error

```
FAILED: checkToSeeIfCampaignQualifiedTest("chrome", "latest", "Windows 10", public void com.tests.AutomationTest.checkToSeeIfCampaignQualifiedTest(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.reflect.Method) throws java.lang.InterruptedException,java.rmi.UnexpectedException,java.net.MalformedURLException)
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected token return
  (Session info: chrome=68.0.3440.106)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 11 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'W104NVJJ82', ip: '10.150.49.236', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{mobileEmulationEnabled=false, hasTouchScreen=false, platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=false, goog:chromeOptions={debuggerAddress=localhost:56323}, acceptInsecureCerts=false, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, setWindowRect=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=, applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e), userDataDir=C:\Users\ALVARO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir13164_31533}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=68.0.3440.106, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, locationContextEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: f3e9c0d1f0f43aa7dfb9f17fbe62a299
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:215)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:671)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript(RemoteWebDriver.java:573)
    at com.pages.HP.checkTestWasClassifiedLive(HP.java:79)
    at com.tests.AutomationTest.checkToSeeIfCampaignQualifiedTest(AutomationTest.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:580)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:716)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:988)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

anyone knows how to solve it?

Edit: new stack-trace

```
FAILED: checkToSeeIfCampaignQualifiedTest("chrome", "latest", "Windows 10", public void com.tests.AutomationTest.checkToSeeIfCampaignQualifiedTest(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.reflect.Method) throws java.lang.InterruptedException,java.rmi.UnexpectedException,java.net.MalformedURLException)
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
  (Session info: chrome=68.0.3440.106)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 10 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'W104NVJJ82', ip: '10.150.49.236', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{mobileEmulationEnabled=false, hasTouchScreen=false, platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=false, goog:chromeOptions={debuggerAddress=localhost:57778}, acceptInsecureCerts=false, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, setWindowRect=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=, applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e), userDataDir=C:\Users\ALVARO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir9528_23420}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=68.0.3440.106, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, locationContextEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: ef45e192317fdfe11aa12eb90817ec78
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:215)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:671)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript(RemoteWebDriver.java:573)
    at com.HP.checkTestWasClassifiedLive(HP.java:80)
    at com.AutomationTest.checkToSeeIfCampaignQualifiedTest(AutomationTest.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:580)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:716)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:988)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to

```
return checkClassified();
```

in the end. just

```
checkClassified();
```

The return data from the execution will be according to the documentation:

https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html

see section on *executeScript*

Comment: I've made some changes to convert to Boolean instead of boolean, and inside the function..but now I'm getting an Runtime.evaluate threw exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier ...I've ran this function in the browser console, there was an issue there, because of the global JS variable arguments, so changing the name there worked, but how to do it here?

Comment: @alvarosps Can you attach the stack trace?

Comment: I also tried changing the single quotes ' on the tool.getOffer function from ' to \" so wouldn't have a problem in java..but made no difference

Comment: @alvarosps its harder to spot then the original question. if you say that in console it works with renaming arguments, then do the same thing. After all, in your script you know exactly which data you pass as a method parameters, so you can adjust method logic accordingly. A good way to develop these things, is to start with the minimal working function, and then start adding more logic.